# How to write many to many sql script

Tags: mysql, sql, string, join, group-by

How to write many to many sql script

**students**

```
id | name
```

**classes**

```
id | name
```

**student_classes**

```
id | student_id | class_id
```

Result must be like this

```
id | name | classes

1  | Bob  | Class 1, Class 2
2  | Sara | Class 2
3  | Jon  | -
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 1):

That's a join, and aggregation (or the other way around). The actual syntax for string aggregation varies across databases, but the logic is:

```
select s.*, c.classes
from students s
inner join (
    select sc.student_id, string_agg(c.name, ',') classes
    from classes c
    inner join student_classes sc on sc.class_id = c.id
    group by sc.student_id
) c on c.student_id = s.id
```

If your database does not support `string_agg()`, just replace it with the equivalent function (Oracle has `listagg()`, MySQL has `group_concat()`, ...).

Comment: Unknown column 'sc.student_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @karen: my bad. Fixed.